# Traefik two frontends on one backend different ports

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm running traefik 1.7.8 and created a container via docker-compose with following labels and frontend rules:

```
    labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.data.frontend.rule=Host:data.${DOMAINNAME}"
  - "traefik.data.port=324"
  - "traefik.data.protocol=http"
  - "traefik.webtools.frontend.rule=Host:webtools.${DOMAINNAME}"
  - "traefik.webtools.port=334"
  - "traefik.webtools.protocol=http"
  - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSSeconds=315360000"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.browserXSSFilter=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.contentTypeNosniff=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.forceSTSHeader=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLHost=DOMAIN.COM"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSIncludeSubdomains=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.STSPreload=true"
  - "traefik.frontend.headers.frameDeny=true"
```

I would like to access via data.DOMAIN.COM port 324 of the container and via webtools.DOMAIN.COM port 334 of the container.

After everything has started up I have one frontend and one backend for the rule "data" but the "webtools" is missing.

Based on the documentation it should just work out fine: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers-with-multiple-ports-segment-labels

Do i miss an obvious mistake?

Thank you!

EDIT:
a shutdown and restart of all containers has resolved the issue.